# Using cross product find direction vector of line joining point of intersection of line and plane and foot of perpendicular from line to plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

> A line with equation $r=a+\lambda\vec{d}$ meets plane $\pi$ with equation $r.\hat{n}=k$ at point P.
> Point Q lies in $\pi$ and is the foot of the perpendicular from A to $\pi$.
> Find the direction vector of line PQ.

By solving $(a+\lambda\vec{d}).\hat{n}=k$, I was able to find the position vector of P. Then by finding the intersection of line AQ and plane I was able to find the position vector of Q and hence the direction vector PQ. 
However, the answer can be found simply by finding $(\hat{n}\times \vec{d})\times \hat{n}$ where $\times$ is cross-product. I don't understand why.

Here's what I know :
The cross-product of 2 vectors gives a 3rd vector perpendicular to the 2 vectors.
Line PQ lies on plane so direction vector PQ $\perp \hat{n}$. Also,
AQ is parallel to $\hat{n}$.

The first part $w=(\hat{n}\times \vec{d})$ gives a vector perpendicular to line and parallel to plane. Won't $w\times n$ give a vector perpendicular to the plane again?
I can't understand the geometric interpretation of $(\hat{n}\times \vec{d})\times \hat{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segment $PQ$ lies in a plane that is spanned by the perpendicular to the plane  $n$  and the direction vector $d$, so the normal to this plane is $n \times d$.  But $PQ$ also lies in the plane whose normal is $n$, hence the direction vector of $PQ$ must be along the vector $(n \times d) \times n $

Comment: Did the fact that Q is the foot of the perpendicular imply that the direction vector d spans the plane containing segment PQ? Or is the information given about foot of perpendicular irrelevant?

Comment: That plane is the plane containing the triangle $APQ$ so it is spanned by $AP$ which is along vector $d$, and $AQ$ which is along $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this line $r=a+\lambda\vec{d}$  is intersecting plane $\pi: \vec{r}.\hat n = k$

- The cross product of $\hat n \times \hat{d} = \hat{u_1}$ this $\hat{u_1}$ will be the **unit vector normal to the plane** of line containing line $r=a+\lambda\vec{d}$ and plane $\pi: \vec{r}.\hat n = k$
- Now, we take the cross product of **$\hat{u_1}$ and $\hat n$:** **$\hat {u_2} = \hat {u_1} \times \hat n$** will be the required unit vector.
- **Note:** Here the **$\hat {u_2}$** depends on the unit vector $\hat d$ I mean
  $\hat u_2  = \hat {u_1} \times \hat n $ or $\hat {u_2} =  \hat n \times \hat {u_1}$

*Find the direction vector of line PQ.*

Here, I used unit vectors only as you were interested in the direction of $\vec{PQ}$;

Comment: I understood the first bullet point but not the second. How did you know that the cross product of u1 and u2 gives the direction vector of PQ?

Comment: @Bunny Actually, the fact is $\hat u_2$ is perpendicular to the plane created by normal of plane$\pi$ and line $r = a + \lambda d$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be the angle between ${\bf n}$ and ${\bf d},$ and $\beta$ be the angle between ${\bf n}$ and the perpendicular to both ${\bf n}$ and ${\bf d}.$

$$( \hat{\bf n} \times {\bf d} ) \times \hat{\bf n}$$

1. has magnitude $$\Big(\Vert\hat{\bf n}\Vert \,\Vert{\bf
       d}\Vert|\,\sin\alpha|\Big)\,\Vert\hat{\bf
       n}\Vert\,|\sin\beta|\\
       =\Vert\hat{\bf n}\Vert \,\Big(\Vert{\bf
       d}\Vert|\,\sin\alpha|\Big)\,\Vert\hat{\bf
       n}\Vert\,|\sin\beta|
       \\=(1)\,PQ\,(1)\,|\sin90^\circ |\\=PQ;$$
2. - is perpendicular to $\hat{\bf n},$
   - and to the normal of the plane spanned by $\hat{\bf n}$ and ${\bf d},$ i.e., lies in the plane spanned by $\hat{\bf n}$ and ${\bf d};$

   thus is collinear to $\vec{PQ}$ (which is also perpendicular to $\hat{\bf n}$).

Comment: Can you elaborate how you obtained magnitude in number 1. Which term gave PQ?

Comment: No I did not downvote any answer. After drawing the triangle, I understood what you meant. Thank you.